# Differences between QueueBackgroundWorkItem (Action <CancellationToken>) and QueueBackgroundWorkItem (Func <CancellationToken, Task>)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, fire-and-forget

I was looking for a way to send background emails in Asp.Net without having to wait for them completely and came across the "HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem" method. I noticed that there are two types of overloads: QueueBackgroundWorkItem (Action ) and QueueBackgroundWorkItem (Func <CancellationToken, Task>), but I honestly didn't understand the difference.
Could someone kindly explain the to me difference if they know about it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netframework-4.8), the `Action` variant:

> QueueBackgroundWorkItem takes a Task-returning callback; the work item will be considered finished when the callback returns.

The first part of that statement is incorrect. However, the second is accurate - when the method returns, it's considered complete. The `Func` variant:

> QueueBackgroundWorkItem takes a Task-returning callback; the work item will be considered finished when the returned Task transitions to a terminal state.

This is all true now. You provide a callback that returns a `Task`, and the system doesn't consider the work to be complete until that `Task` is finished. This variant works quite nicely with an `async` `Task` returning method which then allows you to use `await`s within the method.

So, if you're doing all of your work synchronously and are finished when your callback returns, you can use the `Action` variant. Otherwise choose the `Func` variant.